# dealing with line equations in not proportional scales

Tags: python, time-series, degrees

I am calculating trendlines for stock market, and want to know the angle between 2 lines.
The X-axis is epoch timestamp (in ms) and Y-axis is the price. 
The problem is that because epoch ts's number is so high (lets say 1,591,205,309,000 ms) and the price per share can vary from 0.078$ to 10,000$, the scales are not proportional. 
I am also a trader, and when I trade I see charts as described in the picture below:
[image]
This way, the ploting is probably scaling the axes to fit in some way (compressing X axis and stretching Y axis).
Also, this scaling is generic (whether I am looking at 5 minute chart or 1 day chart), when I draw lines (in the same timeframe), I see it in a comfortable way. 
If you will take those lines and plot it on a ts/price graph, you will probably see 2 parallel lines.

I also must keep the line equation in ts because I need to forcast when the trade will be in the future (giving it the ts, and it returns the price where it will be at)

Right now, when calculating this angle I get around 0.0003 degrees, I want to get the degrees of the lines like in the chart above.

Comment: most probably the example you show is between a large timeframe, not between a few ms, then it would give the same angle as you get

Comment: @NikosM. each candle in the image is 1 hour = 3,600,000 ms, and price ranges are 0.36-0.32